# Recover from failed score submission in openfient

Tags: android, openfeint, leaderboard

If a game has no internet connection and hence fails to submit any highscores to openfeint, then how can it trigger a resubmission later on when there is a connection.

At the moment I have it working so that openfeint only tries to submit a score when the local highscore is lower than the new score. The problem here is that a highscore could fail and then the player may never break the (unsubmitted) highscore and therefore his score will never be submitted.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your offline config file setup properly it should cache the unsaved score locally and unload it when the opportunity presents itself.

Comment: Sounds too good to be true. I heard somewhere that openfient were being really slow about bringing offline support to android, are you sure this isn't an iOS only feature?